# Filter of rhs with arules/apriori is not working

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I'm using arules::apriori with a binary matrix and want to only create rules that have one particular column on the RHS. This is specified in the documentation but doesn't seem to work. It is easy enough to filter it post hoc to get this but I waste a lot of computational time calculating all the rules in the first place.

Example:

```
library(arules)
data = data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10000,1, 0.6), nrow=1000))
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) data[,i] = as.factor(data[,i])
dsRules = as(data, "transactions")
rules = apriori(dsRules, 
    parameter=list(support = 0.1, minlen = 3, maxlen = 3, target= "rules", confidence = 0.7), 
    appearance = list(rhs = c("X1=1")))
```

rules now contains 3378 rules

```
rules.sub = subset(rules, subset = (rhs %pin% "X1=1"))
```

rules.sub contains 172 rules

In my actual data I go from millions of results to ~4000 which is a huge difference.

Answer (score 4):

Nsfy, there is an easier way to do this.  You need to add `default='lhs'`, as in `appearance=list(rhs='X1=1',default='lhs')`.  This will limit the rhs to only `X1=1`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was reading the documentation wrong. In case others stumble on this:

The documentation for rhs is *character vectors giving the labels of the items which may only appear in the corresponding place of the rules/itemsets.* So my code was saying that item X1 can only appear in the rhs not that the rhs can only contain X1.

To get around this, you specify all other elements to be in the lhs such as

```
keep = names(data)
keep = keep[-1] #remove 1st feature
keepnames = c(paste0(keep, "=1"), paste0(keep, "=0"))
rules = apriori(dsRules, 
parameter=list(support = 0.1, minlen = 3, maxlen = 3, target= "rules", confidence = 0.7), 
appearance = list(lhs = keepnames))
```